Отображение настроения сообщения в веб приложении с использованием AWS Comprehend
Необходимо анализировать сообщение и выводить его настроение используя lambda function и js для отображения результата
Мой html код
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <label for="text">Your text</label>
            <textarea id="text"></textarea>
            <button onclick="SubmitText()">Submit text</button>
            <div id="result" class="result"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>```




import boto3
import json

comprehend = boto3.client('comprehend')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        body = json.loads(event['body'])
        text = body['review']

        sentiment_response = comprehend.detect_sentiment(
            Text=review_text,
            LanguageCode='en'  
        )
        
        
        response = {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'headers': {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            'body': json.dumps({
                'Sentiment': sentiment_response['Sentiment']
            })
        }
        return response
        
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", str(e))
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps({
                'message': 'Error processing your request',
                'error': str(e)
            })
        }
async function SubmitText() {
                const Text = document.getElementById('text').value;
                try {
                    const response = await fetch('https://br3nuogj50.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/review', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                        body: JSON.stringify({'text': Text})
                    });
                    const result = await response.json();
                    document.getElementById('result').textContent = 'Sentiment:' + result.Sentiment;
                } catch {
                    document.getElementById('result').textContent = 'Error'
                }
            }




добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
